# Using SSIS Web Service Task with WCF

Tags: wcf, ssis, service, task

I am using SQL Server 2008 SSIS for importing data to the DB and .Net 3.5 SP1 for Creating the WCF service.

In the import task I am trying to use the Web Service Task to report to a WCF service.
At first I encountered a problem with the WCF WSDL, the Web Service task couldn't get their code generated from the metadata exposed by the WCF service. So I found a blog post at   [Christian Weyer's Blog](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html)
talking just about that.

Now after I can successfully load a WCF service to the Web Service Task and get the functions generated just fine from the WSDL I encountered another problem.
I get an error from the SSIS package at runtime saying that "Method 'ProxyNamespace.MyService.GetData' not found."

The full Error is:

Error: 0xC002F304 at Web Service Task False, Web Service Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: Could not execute the Web method. The error is: Method 'ProxyNamespace.MyService.GetData' not found..
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser taskVariableDispenser)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".

I know that the simple solution is going back to regular Web Service, but I really don't want to go there.

Thanks,

Omri.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the SSIS web service task, maybe you can code it in a script task.  You can use vb.net in 2005 - c# as well in 2008 I think.